# How to use scss files of angularjs in angular 4 project

Tags: angular

I am working on migration of my angularjs project to angular 4.I followed the steps in angular documentation for migrating and I was able to migrate my code .However i could link the scss files of angularjs to angular project.Could anyone suggest me how to do this?

Comment: How are you doing the migration. Is the upgraded project using webpack? Shedding more light on your new project structure will help in providing useful answers.

Comment: no i have not used the webpack just systemjs.I followed the official docs for migration

Comment: Please specify the version of Angular and of Angular command line interface.

https://github.com/angular/angular
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

Scss is not supported right away you could add some sass components to allow your angular project to use sass.
Try this:
https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/wiki/How-to-include-SCSS-in-components

Comment: Scss can be supported right away in Angular 4. Same goes for: Sass

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles