# SCSS in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, sass, stylesheet

I'm trying to use a scss file as a stylesheet in AngularJS

I already tried different approaches:

In Index.html:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='scss/_app.scss'/>
```

and also

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/scss' href='scss/_app.scss'/>
```

Or importing it in a normal css file:

```
@import '../../scss/_app.scss';
```

Both ways don't really seem to be working.. since I'm using bootstrap 4 there shouldn't be a problem with using scss files

I'm thankful for every help!

Comment: You may find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43974225/how-to-use-scss-files-of-angularjs-in-angular-4-project

Answer (score 0):

Browsers can't read .scss files.

It is totally irrelevant if you are using AngularJS.

First you will need to compile the .scss file to .css file.
Another thing to note is that when compiling .scss files, if the filename is starting with an underscore it will not create a file. So you'll first need to rename the file to 'app.scss'

Once that's done and you now have compiled your .css file, all you need to do is:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='path/to/your/file/app.css'/>
```

as you normally would.

The @import feature from .scss is only for partials, and the way to declare to the compiler to not output a file is by adding the underscore before the filename.

[read here about @import feature of scss](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import)